# Looping item based on the value of array inside a angular html loop

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So I have this weird problem (or might just say my logical problem) on how do I loop an item inside angular html, instead of the value of array must be access something like 0 - 1 - 2 by (keys) it doing something like this 2 - 0 - 1

I will just attach [stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzsigw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) , I dont know why it occurs like this but something is not right. I might thinking it wrong

Comment: Can you provide some more details on how your example is not working? I opened your example, and all the numbers appear to be in order.

Comment: in the example the one (word) must have a count of 0 , 1 , 2 instead of 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 since the function getData() will get the index of the object array and point the value of the array based on the index of the object and push some numbers to arrayCbox to get the length and will reflect to html.

Partially the output from the html is wrong because index 0 of the array must be 3, so the output must be from 0, 2 not from 0,4

Comment: I'm having a ton of trouble understanding your example because `getData` is super weird. It changes a component variable on the go for every call, and that in turn probably breaks the nested ngFor. What did you expect to be printed on the screen?

I would recommend you avoid at all costs functions with side effects being called from the HTML. You're just inviting trouble and complications to your program.

Comment: @Badashi so the expected output must be something like this one below numbers are 012 , two below numbers 0,1,2,3 , three below numbers 0,1,2,3,4 something like this. "I would recommend you avoid at all costs functions with side effects being called from the HTML" I will take note for this. but for my case do I need it or there is some method like (loop) that will take a number and loop it depends on the number of object value

Comment: The main issue here is that you have a `arrayCbox` variable that is, in a sense, global to your component. However, every call to `getData` will alter that `arrayCbox` - and there's no way to guarantee that you'll have the correct `arrayCbox` for each inner loop of your `ngFor`s. Instead, you should have some way to build your `arrayCbox` for each different element of `someObjectArray`. Maybe if you show us what problem you are trying to solve, we can figure out a different way to approach it.

Comment: @Badashi so I am trying to solve is I need to have checkbox in each sentences. I already know how to get each sentences, note that that object contains sentences but before looping the object i will have to check each of the value to check how many sentences does the value have, after that I will put the number of sentences to an somearray to be called later on that function getdata() the data will display in a table something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/0J5ca20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my problem instead doing that complicated thingy i did this

> in HTML

```
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of checkNumReq(arraySentences[ind]); let in = index;">
          {{index}}
        </ion-item>
```

> in TS file

```
  checkNumReq(num_req:any){
    return new Array(num_req);
  }
```